# Треугольный background

Tags: html5, css3, background

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! При наведении на блок появляется кнопка и полупрозрачный желтый фон. Как его сделать? Пробовал сделать с помощью свойства border, но тогда слетает весь контент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

добавь блоку :after , в нем опиши квадрат с желтым бг , и с помощью свойства rotate и position absolut вынеси его так как тебе нужно , и на сам блок overflow hidden что бы обрезать ненужное

Comment: есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: какие проблемы с этим вариантом ?или скажите какие требования

Comment: Описал как Вы сказали, но желтый бг не появляется

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ow3efx0/1/ , пример , только настройте прозрачность и позицию чуть лучше как вам надо , на половину блока

Comment: все равно не получилось( могут быть проблемы из-за flexbox?

Comment: сделайте проект на jsfiddle , гадать в чем причина нет времени

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fronick7/gvs47mqq/

Comment: background-color а не backround-color , и он появиться , останется только отпозиционировать нормально

Comment: Ахахах, который раз допускаю такую ошибку. Спасибо, большое)